# Freeing a pointer from memory in c#

Tags: c#

I'm dealing with pointer in C# using `fixed{}` phrases.

I placed my code inside the brackets of the fixed statement and want to know if the Garbage collection will handle the pointer freeing after the fixed statement

```
fixed{int * p=&x}
{
// i work with x.
}
```

if not how can I free it?

Comment: The reference or value is allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pointer points to a managed object (`x`) so there is nothing to worry about: the pointer  does not need to be freed (or rather, it goes out of scope at the end of the `fixed` block) and the pointee `x` itself is managed by the GC.

Answer (score 0):

Some similar code in C will things make more clear:

```
{
   int x;     // allocates space for x

   {
     int *p=&x; // does not allocate for something p points to (only for p)

     // ...
   } // leaves inner scope, p vanishes, *p is not deallocated
   // ...
} // leaves outer scope, x is deallocated
```

The C# code does essentially the same.